# Force shell to ignore shebang

Tags: shell-script, android

I'm trying to run `./configure` in Termux but the file has the following line:

```
#! /bin/sh
```

As there is no `/bin/sh` in Termux, the script fails to run.

```
bash configure
```

works for a while until it executes another configure file that also has that line:

```
configure: error: cannot run /bin/sh ./config.sub
```

Is there a way to force the shell to ignore `#!`?

Comment: The shell doesn't interpret the shebang (how could it, you need to read the shebang in order to know which interpreter to use in the first place!), the kernel does.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Only mostly true. It's not hard to read a file after all. http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/execute_cmd.c#n5520

Comment: The shebang is already ignored by the shell (it starts with a "#"). It is used by the kernel to decide which interpreter (which shell, most of the time) will read the file.

Comment: @Olivier not necessarily, in some cases the shell will act on the shebang line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the [Termux FAQ](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/FAQ#Why_do_I_keep_getting_.27.2Fbin.2Fsh_bad_interpreter.27_error.3F): the best way to fix this is to install [termux-exec](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux-exec) by running

```
pkg install termux-exec
```

and restarting your Termux session. Your scripts will then work without needing any changes.